# Is there a way to deactivate "Your account is activated"-emails in WordPress to new users?

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for a way to deactivate the "user account activated" emails from Wordpress, which are sent to the user after registration. The emails are as follows:

Hello XY,
Your account on [BLOG] has been activated! Find your login details below.
Login page: [BLOG/wp-login.php]
Username: XY
Password: Use the password you entered when you registered your account or set a new password using the link below.

[BLOG]
This message was sent by [BLOG]

Since I have connected the registration with my newsletter tool via a rest api and a double opt in takes place, this email is superfluous and confusing. However, I cannot find a way to deactivate it. Maybe someone has an idea. Thanks in advance.

I tried to disable the emails to the user with the following function in the functions.php file:

```
`function disable_new_user_notifications() {
    return false;
}

add_filter('wp_notify_postauthor', 'disable_new_user_notifications');
add_filter('wp_notify_moderator', 'disable_new_user_notifications');
add_filter('wp_password_change_notification', 'disable_new_user_notifications');
add_filter('wp_new_user_notification', 'disable_new_user_notifications');
add_filter('wpmu_signup_user_notification_subject', 'disable_new_user_notifications');
`
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the wordpress default hooks you should have something like this:

```
remove_action( 'register_new_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications' );
remove_action( 'edit_user_created_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications', 10, 2 );
```

Those action are added in this file: wp-includes/default-filters.php around line 510 in Wp version 6.3.1. If you don't have any other third party plugins that should do it

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. WordPress keeps sending those eMails after registration.

Comment: Do you have any 3rd party plugins that may add or alter user registration emails?

Comment: Nope, I don't. Just to make sure I'm getting this right, I'm removing the actions in my functions.php right?